# How to map two entities in the one Symfony Form

Tags: forms, symfony, mapping, entities

The problem I am having now is related to entities and forms in Symfony2.

While creating the form that refers to one entity I can simply wire it by saying:

```
$user = new User();
$form->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
...
$manager->persist($user);
$manager->flush();
```

And that is working fine. But the problem raises when I have more complex form that is built based on other forms, e.g.

So, let's imagine I have a form called **RegistrationType** that contains two other forms called **UserType** wired to **User** entity and **ProfileType** wired to **Profile** entity.

Now, how can I handle that in the controller? I mean, I cannot do something like:

```
$user = new User();
$profile = new Profile();
$form->createForm(new RegisterType(), $user, $profile);
OR
$form->createForm(new RegisterType(), [$user, $profile]);
...
$manager->persist($user);
$manager->flush();

$profile->setUserId($user->getId());
$manager->persist($profile);
$manager->flush();
```

If I pass only $user, like so

```
$form->createForm(new RegisterType(), $user);
```

Symfony will complain that there are properties that are not mapped, of course I can set them to 'mapped' => false but then I have to set them later on manually.

What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `UserType`, `ProfileType` and `RegistrationType` forms. `RegistrationType` should add `UserType` and `ProfileType` as its children. Create `Registration` DTO and set it as `data_class` for `RegistrationType`. Then you can write something like

```
$user = new User();
$profile = new Profile();
$form->createForm(new RegistrationType(), 
           new Registration($user, $profile));
```

Comment: In many cases you can just use an array in place of a Registration DTO.  array('user' => $user, 'profile' => $profile);

Comment: Yes, in that particular case it's also a nice solution